# ¿Cuál palabra es "ouo"?

Tags: ortografía

Leyendo una edición antigua de *Las Sergas de Esplandian*, me encontré una palabra que no pude entender.  Aquí lo muestro con imagen:

[image]

Transcrito al alfabeto moderno, se lee:

> Sabed que ala diestra mano delas Yndias ouo vna Ysla llamada California mucho llegada ala parte del parayso terrenal...

y en la ortografía moderna:

> Sabed que ala diestra mano de las Indias **[ouo]** una isla llamada California mucho llegada a la parte del paraiso terrenal...

¿Pero cuál palabra tiene significado con *ouo*?

Comment: Tal vez esto ayude: en [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Spanish_language) "las manos se ouo de vntar" aparece como "las manos se las tuvo que untar"

Comment: Tiene pinta de ser "hubo".

Comment: Y bienvenido a Spanish.SE, muy buena pregunta :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Según el "Diccionario crítico etimológico castellano e hispánico" de J. Corominas y J.A. Pascual, **ouo** es una forma antigua del verbo **haber** que equivale a **hubo** .

> Tan grand pesar **ouo** el Rey don alfonsso...
>
> Cantar de Mio Cid (c. 1200)

Comment: Y se pronuncio *ouo* como "ovo"?

Comment: @Joe sí, más o menos.  La *u* consonante probablemente tenía algún sonido parecido pero no exactamente como la /b/ moderna.  Pero la vocal era sin duda una /o/

Answer (score 2):

> Sabed que a la diestra mano de la India **hubo** una isla llamada California, muy llegada al paraíso terrenal...

Debido a que soy de la Baja California, he visto muchas veces el fragmento.